# Image Panel doesn't show up immediately in JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, jframe

So I have a class which extends `JPanel` and on which I draw a `BufferedImage` (in its `paintComponent` method).
However, the image doesn't show up until I resize the window. Any idea how to fix this?
I've tried repaint without much success.

Comment: If you don't get a decent answer soon, you should show pertinent code. You really should have done this from the get go without our having to ask, you know.

Comment: For better help & sooner, consider posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: See my comment on @DoorKnobs answer, also something must be going wrong that you would need to call `repaint()` ( I never have too), well +1 to suggestions on providing some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `validate();` method along with `repaint();`.

```
frame.repaint();
frame.validate();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you! it works like a charm! But some explanation on this would be appreciated. :D

Comment: @abcXYZ 
calling `setVisible` BEFORE you've finished adding components?

Comment: no. actually what fixed the problem was the validate(). I called repaint() on the panel that contained the image and call validate() on the frame containing this panel. The frame itself is already visible, so I didn't have to call setVisible()

Comment: @abcXYZ: again, next time please remove all doubt -- please show code. It's not fair to make us guess.

Comment: @Doorknob, the above would be counter productive, rather `validate()` and than `repaint()`, Even than why is `validate()` necessary? Even better than `validate()` is `revalidate()`, as `revalidate()` covers `validate()`. `validate()` is used when new components are added to a visible component, whereas `revalidate()` is used when components are removed/added from a visible component.